# Changing scroll speed on LazyRow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

Looking at the documentation for `LazyRow` I was wondering if it was possible to reduce the scroll speed, it looks like `LazyRow` inherits from `ScrollState` but I can't find anything useful on how to reduce the speed of the scroll

Comment: [FlingBehaviour](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/FlingBehavior) can help here. You can set it in [LazyRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyRow(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LazyRow doesn't have a parameter to customize scroll speed so you have to do it manually.

You could first capture the scroll gesture something like the below  (from google example [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures) ):

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableSample() {
    // actual composable state
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .scrollable(
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                // Scrollable state: describes how to consume
                // scrolling delta and update offset
                state = rememberScrollableState { delta ->
                    offset += delta
                    delta
                }
            )
            .background(Color.LightGray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(offset.toString())
    }
}
```

Then you have to implement the scroll state at your desired speed for the LazyRow by manually changing the LazyRow's state which is one of the LazyRow parameters.
you will also have to disable LazyRow userscrolling
something like this:

```
LazyRow(
    ...
    state = yourCustomState,
    userScrollEnabled = false,
    ...
){ ... }
```

below is a complete working solution:

```
    var stateIsGood = rememberLazyListState()

    var offset = 0f
    LazyRow(
        modifier =  Modifier
            .scrollable(
                orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                // Scrollable state: describes how to consume
                // scrolling delta and update offset
                state = rememberScrollableState { delta ->
                    offset += delta
                    vm.viewModelScope.launch {
                    //dividing by 8 the delta for 8 times slower horizontal scroll, 
                    //you can change direction by making it a negative number
                        stateIsGood.scrollBy(-delta/8)
                    }
                    delta
                }
            ),
        state = stateIsGood,
        userScrollEnabled = false,

        ) {
        item {
            Text(text = "Header")
        }

        // Add 3 items
        items(3) { index ->
            Text(text = "SCROLL ME First List items : $index")
        }

        // Add 2 items
        items(2) { index ->
            Text(text = "Second List Items: $index")
        }

        // Add another single item
        item {
            Text(text = "Footer")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand, so your saying I must disabled the scrolling in LazyRow then add my custom one like the above?

Comment: Yes I edited my answer and added a working solution

Comment: Is it possible to have some sort of snap to center with this current functionality?

Comment: You can write some custom logic to round to a certain value thus creating the effect

Comment: How'd you mean? I'm just confused as to where I should start. I'm not entirely sure which values to play with to achieve the effect

Comment: You have to first try to understand my answer really well, that's the key, try to implement it as an example and play with it.
You'll see that changes to 'stateIsGood' make the scroll happen,
Then you have to understand how 'stateIsGood.scrollBy(-delta/8)' this call , makes the scrolling happen.
Afterwards you can create a function that will output a different value based on delta...
Start by playing with this solution and fully grasping it :)

Comment: @KTOV your question is resolved. The snapping effect was not a part of the question. David would apparently be happy to assist you with this side question too, but you must mark the answer as correct if your original question has been resolved. Plus, custom scroll implementation is indeed the only way you to implement what you need as of now. No out-of-the box argument is available to set the speed of the scroll, since it defaults to the values used by the Android OS running on the device in concern.

Comment: Are you using the ViewModel's coroutineScope to power your activity? Why not just use the scopes available locally? Every Composable Scope can spawn its own local coroutineScope, while the activity itself also has the handy `lifecycleScope`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of prevent userScroll we can use flingBehavior parameter. When we update initialVelocity it should change fling effect.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun maxScrollFlingBehavior(): FlingBehavior {
    val flingSpec = rememberSplineBasedDecay<Float>()
    return remember(flingSpec) {
        ScrollSpeedFlingBehavior(flingSpec)
    }
}

private class ScrollSpeedFlingBehavior(
    private val flingDecay: DecayAnimationSpec<Float>
) : FlingBehavior {
    override suspend fun ScrollScope.performFling(initialVelocity: Float): Float {
        // Prevent very fast scroll
        val newVelocity =
            if (initialVelocity > 0F) minOf(initialVelocity, 15_000F)
            else maxOf(initialVelocity, -15_000F)

        return if (abs(newVelocity) > 1f) {
            var velocityLeft = newVelocity
            var lastValue = 0f
            AnimationState(
                initialValue = 0f,
                initialVelocity = newVelocity,
            ).animateDecay(flingDecay) {
                val delta = value - lastValue
                val consumed = scrollBy(delta)
                lastValue = value
                velocityLeft = this.velocity
                // avoid rounding errors and stop if anything is unconsumed
                if (abs(delta - consumed) > 0.5f) this.cancelAnimation()
            }
            velocityLeft
        } else newVelocity
    }
}
```

and you can use like this

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
   modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
   flingBehavior = maxScrollFlingBehavior()
) {
   // Content Here
}
```

If you want to implement your own logic, you can update initialVelocity param. Higher its 'absolute' value, the faster it moves.

Answer (score 1):

As a shorter alternative to [David's Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73509870/15880865),

```
@Composable
fun LazyStack(ssd: Int = 1) { // Scroll-Speed-Divisor
    val lazyStackState = rememberLazyListState()
    val lazyStackScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectVerticalDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                lazyStackScope.launch {
                    lazyStackState.scrollBy(-dragAmount / ssd).log("checkpoint")
                }
            }
        },
        state = lazyStackState,
        userScrollEnabled = false
    ) {...}
}
```

And yes, `LazyStack` is short for LazyStackOverflower