what are the alternative of computeVerticalScrollOffset and computeVerticalScrollRange in Compose?
I m working on LazyColumn where I have to create a fastScrollBar indicator,
so what are the alternative of this code in Compose
 var scrollOffset = mRecyclerView!!.computeVerticalScrollOffset()

var verticalScrollRange =  mRecyclerView!!.computeVerticalScrollRange() 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426230/changing-scroll-speed-on-lazyrow
